# How do I search and update most recent record in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a database of laptops with serials and dates returned/deployed, and I want to log deployments and return dates. I have a deployment form which logs the date deployed into a table, and a return form that should find the most recent record for a given serial in that table and then insert the date returned from the form into that serial's record entry.

How would I do this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data it is difficult to advise, but conceptually, something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE 
    DeploymentTable
SET 
    DeploymentTable.ReturnDate = Date()
WHERE 
    DeploymentTable.Serial = 'ABC123' AND
    DeploymentTable.DeploymentDate = DMax("DeploymentDate","DeploymentTable","Serial = 'ABC123'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***DMax*** function

> DMax function to determine maximum value in a specified set of records (a domain).
>  Syntax - DMax( ** Expr, ** Domain, ** Criteria** )

```
Dmax("ID","tblLaptop", "SerialNO='ABCDE'")
```

Above function will get the most recent record (`ID`) from tblLaptop table with Serial no ABCDE.

---

**Procedure to update date**

```
Sub UpdateDate()

 Dim laptopID As Long
 laptopID = DMax("ID", "tblLaptop", "SerialNO='b'")


 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
 DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tblLaptop set ReturnedDate=#" & Date & "# where ID=" & laptopID
 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```